# Order By same column using joined table Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: mother and child.  Each mother has one or more children.

mother:

```
id | name  | age 
1  | name1 | 30
2  | name2 | 40 
3  | name3 | 35
```

child:

```
id | name   | age | id_mother
1  | child1 | 15  | 1 
2  | child2 | 10  | 2
```

<s>The result that I want is order mother order by age ASC and order by their children age asc</s>

**Edit (from comments):** I simply want to order by minimum child age (if child exists), and then by mother age.

For example :

```
id | name  | age 
2  | name2 | 40 
1  | name1 | 30 
3  | name3 | 35
```

I tried this sql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mother m
ORDER BY m.age asc , (SELECT MIN(age) FROM child c WHERE c.id_mother == m.id)
```

but it give just mothers ordered by their age?

Comment: I don't understand your data or the expected output.  You might want to clean up your question a bit.

Comment: `age` column in your expected output does not make sense.

Comment: age to show you why I want this order

Comment: Why isn't mother with `name1` not coming at the top ?

Comment: sorry I edited the order that I want. mother with name 2 came before mother with name 1 because his child is younger than the child of mother with name1

Comment: I think you simply want to order by minimum child age (if child exists), and then by mother age ?

Comment: yes thats what I want

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply want to order by minimum child age (if child exists), and then by mother age.

- In a Correlated Subquery, you can get the minimum age out of the mother's children (if they exist).
- In `ORDER BY`, we will use `IS NOT NULL` to put the cases first in ordering where a minimum child age value exists.

Try:

```
SELECT
  m.*, 
  (SELECT MIN(c.age) 
   FROM child AS c
   WHERE c.id_mother = m.id) AS min_child_age 
FROM mother AS m 
ORDER BY 
  min_child_age IS NOT NULL DESC, 
  min_child_age ASC, 
  m.age ASC
```

---

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table mother 
(id int, name varchar(8), age int);

insert into mother values
(1, 'name1', 30), (2, 'name2', 40), (3, 'name3', 35); 


create table child
(id int , name varchar(8), age int, id_mother int);

insert into child values 
(1  , 'child1' , 15  , 1 ),
(2  , 'child2' , 10  , 2);
```

---

**Result**

```
| id  | name  | age | min_child_age |
| --- | ----- | --- | ------------- |
| 2   | name2 | 40  | 10            |
| 1   | name1 | 30  | 15            |
| 3   | name3 | 35  |               |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x8vQsXRL75pi9ixb9X9eTJ/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
try using this method :
select * from mother;
+----+-------+-----+
| id | name  | age |
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 | name1 |  30 |
|  2 | name2 |  40 |
|  3 | name3 |  35 |
+----+-------+-----+

select * from child;
+----+--------+-----+-----------+
| id | name   | age | id_mother |
+----+--------+-----+-----------+
|  1 | child1 |  15 |         1 |
|  2 | child2 |  10 |         2 |
+----+--------+-----+-----------+


SELECT mo1. * , (SELECT MIN( ch1.age ) FROM child AS ch1 WHERE ch1.id_mother = mo1.id) AS child_age FROM mother AS mo1 ORDER BY child_age IS NOT NULL DESC , child_age ASC ;
+----+-------+-----+-----------+
| id | name  | age | child_age |
+----+-------+-----+-----------+
|  2 | name2 |  40 |        10 |
|  1 | name1 |  30 |        15 |
|  3 | name3 |  35 |      NULL |
+----+-------+-----+-----------+
```